# Tire size for greater than factory wheel width?

Tags: tires, scion

I have a 2006 Scion tC, and I bought a separate set of wheels to make summer / winter switching easier. I realized after purchase that the wheels are an inch wider than stock… but I called several dealerships and they believed they should still fit, so I plan on keeping them. Now I am looking for a tire size that will fit these, but checking multiple websites seems to show different results for the proper size:

- TireRack shows 215/45-17
- Figment Industries shows 225/45-17
- Tyre size calculator shows either 235 or 245

I just want to make sure I get some tires that do not fall off the wheels, and also do not rub. Does anyone have any suggestions?

New wheel dimensions:

- Diameter: 17 in
- Width: 8 in
- Offset: +35mm
- Hub bore: 63.3mm

Stock wheel dimensions:

- Diameter: 17 in
- Width: 7 in
- Offset: 45mm
- Hub bore: 54.1mm

Comment: If you already have the wheels, you need to ensure they are going to fit the vehicle. "Dry" fit them by taking one of the original wheels off and putting a new one on its place. Spin the rim to ensure it is going to spin freely and not hit any vehicle components, especially the brakes and suspension. Do this front and back. Two things I'd be worried about before you get tires. The offset is quite a bit different. This could cause issues. Secondly, the hub bore is different. If the new rims didn't come with the correct centering rings to match your car, this could also cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

I'd wouldn't use 8" rims unless your really know what you are doing.  You will put [all sorts of stresses](https://www.lesschwab.com/article/wheels/what-is-wheel-offset.html) on the car.  8" wide rims are not for a first generation Scion, only the second gen.

See [here](https://www.wheel-size.com/size/scion/tc/2006/) for documented wheel/tire options for your make and model.  If you want a wider stance, go with tested [hub spacers](https://fastscions.com/c-1203364-shop-by-scion-scion-tc-parts-scion-tc-wheel-accessories.html).  The most aggressive, "W" speed rating can be had with an 18" rim diameter combined with an aspect ratio of 225/40.

The tire options you mention are all for 17" diameter wheels.  Since in general it's best to stay [within a 3% diameter](https://www.lesschwab.com/article/tires/tire-size-calculator-what-size-tires-should-you-get.html) size, up to 235 is max.

Comment: Much appreciated for your answer. I had just put in my year/make/model on tire rack and it showed me this wheel as one option. Custom wheels are much more difficult than I had realized… thanks for sharing.